# Wierd issue comparing Strings in Servlets with Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have this wierd problem with my servlet, I can't delete an element of an object if I pass variable to the `delete` method, but if I pass a String that contains an element that already exists it works like a charm. Here's my code:

The `delete` method:

```
public void delete(String t) {
    for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        if(list.get(i).getTitre() == t) list.remove(i); 
    }
}
```

My servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    String titre = (String) request.getParameter("T1");   
    Biblio b = (Biblio) request.getSession().getAttribute("list");     

    // here this works which means "titre" isnt null
    b.add(titre, "b", 1); 

    // this also works which means the delete method works correctly 
    b.delete("a"); 

    // this doesn't work, i get no error, the page load but the item is still there 
   b.delete(titre);

   request.getSession().setAttribute("list", b);    

   this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/main.jsp")
       .forward(request, response);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

The issue was quiet simple: I should have used `equals` instead of `==` in my `delete` method.

Comment: you dont compare Strings using `==`. use `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` if case sensitivity does not matter

Comment: well that's embarrassing, i've used equals and i got a javanulpointer but apparently equals wasnt the problem, thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dont compare Strings using `==`. use `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` if case sensitivity does not matter